# jQuery scroll on hover

Tags: jquery, scroll

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div class="top-corner"></div> <!-- absolute, top: 0 -->
<div class="bottom-corner"></div> <!--  absolute, bottom: 0 -->
<a href="#" class="top-link">top</a> <!--  fixed, top 50%, left 0 -->
<a href="#" class="bottom-link">bottom</a> <!--  fixed, top 60%, left 0 -->
<div style="padding: 1500px 0;"></div> <!--  for scroll test -->
</body>
```

Using scrollto plugin
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

**JS**

```
$(".top-link").hover(function(){
    $("body").scrollTo($(".top-corner"), 3000);
},function(){
    // stop on unhover
});
$(".bottom-link").hover(function(){
    $("body").scrollTo($(".bottom-corner"), 3000);
},function(){
    // stop on unhover
});
```

Animation works on hover. **How to stop it on unhover?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$(".top-link").hover(function(){
    $("body").scrollTo($(".top-corner"), 3000);
},function(){
     $("body").stop();
    // stop on unhover
});
$(".bottom-link").hover(function(){
    $("body").scrollTo($(".bottom-corner"), 3000);
},function(){
    $("body").stop();
    // stop on unhover
});
```

if the callbacks are just the same, you can also do this,

```
$(".bottom-link, .top-link").hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $("body").scrollTo($this, 3000);
},function(){
    $("body").stop();
    // stop on unhover
});
```

Comment: It's very abrupt. I added this to help a little: $('body').stop().scrollTo('-=20px', 300);